# Падает вёрстка в Опере на 50px по вертикале

Tags: opera, html, css

Доброго времени суток коллеги!

Проблема заключается в следующем. Именно в браузере опера, при заходе на две ссылки, main div в котором расположен весь контент сайта, падает пикселей на 50 по вертикале. 
 Не могу понять в чём проблема ибо сайт полностью адаптирован под PHP и всё, везде одинаково, но именно на двух страницах у прилагаемого ниже сайта проблема такая существует.

http://81.200.23.210/project

ссылки - "Девушки" и "Юноши".

Причём если вы обратите внимание, открыв одну из указанных выше ссылок сайта именно через оперу, то использовав <ul> меню, он возвращается на искомое место, но это до перезагрузки страницы.

**отвечать на свой вопрос не могу.
Всем спасибо за попытку помочь! Проблему решил самостоятельно! Тему можно закрывать**

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что пример кода уже недоступен, и смысл вопроса утерян.

Answer (score 0):

Еще шрифт крупных надписей "девушки и юноши" под верхней лентой с логотипом неправильно в опере отображается. Может это как-то связано между собой.

Кстати сочетание слов Девушки, Юноши и Услуги в одном месте на ленте создает впечатление, что это не фотостудия, а нечто иное. Кроме того что-то мне подсказывает, что это можно решить в индусском стиле абсолютным вертикальным позиционированием этой надписи через CSS, действующим только в том случае, если пользователь зашел через оперу.

Comment: Шрифт пробовал уменьшать, увы результатов не дало. 

По поводу ссылок на ленте, не стоит иронизировать, так предложил и утвердил заказчик, а моё дело маленькое. Тупо сделать как хочет.
По поводу индийского стиля, я бы возможно  принял бы предложение и рассмотрел его, но к сожалению есть не-кто, кто не разделит наших соображений :)

Answer (score 0):

что то мне подсказывает что это overflow у тэга body

Comment: нет.... это не overflow :( через указанный URL смотрите Вы, а я экспериментирую на дубликате.
Ваш вариант я уже пробовал вчера.. увы...